# how to get target of vue draggable

Tags: vue.js, draggable, vuedraggable

I am using vue draggable element like this

```
 <b-row v-for="(stage,index) in Pdata" :key="index">
        

      <!-- people group 1 -->
      <b-col  md="6">
        <h6 class="text-primary font-weight-bold mb-2">
          {{stage.stage}} 
        </h6>

        <!-- draggable -->
        <draggable
          :list="stage.items"
          group="people"
          class="list-group list-group-flush cursor-move"
         
        >
          <b-list-group-item
            v-for="listItem in stage.items"
            :key="listItem.id"
            tag="li"
          >  
            <div class="d-flex">
                <b-card> 
                   <b-card-text >
                       {{listItem.name}}
                       </b-card-text> 

                </b-card>

              <!-- <b-avatar :text="listItem.name.slice(0,2)" />
              <div class="ml-25">
                <b-card-text class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">
                  {{ listItem.name }}
                </b-card-text>
                <small>{{ listItem.email }}</small>
              </div> -->
            </div>
          </b-list-group-item>
        </draggable>
      </b-col>     
      </b-col> -->
    </b-row>
```

here the structure of Pdata is like this

```
Pdata :[
{stage:'1',
  id:'1'
items:[]
  },
{stage:'2',
  id:'2'
items:[]
  
}
{stage:'3',
  id:'3'
items:[]
  
}
]
```

here after the vue drag operation i want to add element to the particular Stage in which the item is dragged. How can i get the particular stage id in Pdata so that data can be changed in database ?